# Servlet getting NULL Paramaetrs from Form element

Tags: java, html

I have the following simple form element:

```
 <form action="Test" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="vorname" title="Vorname"></input> 
    <input type="text" name="nachname" title="Nachname"></input> 
 <input
        type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

my POST method in the Servlet looks the following way:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {

     System.out.println(request.getParameter("vorname"));


    String var_Name =  request.getParameter("nachname");
    String var_Vorname =  request.getParameter("vorname");

     try {
        con = Datenbankverbindung();

         if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("Verbunden");

            stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into ktzvtest (Name, 
  Vorname)  values (?, ?)");
            stmt.setString(1, var_Name);
            stmt.setString(2, var_Vorname);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.print("erfolgreich");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
     try {
        con.close();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

So the two variables var_Name and var_Vorname are alway NULL. What's the problem ?

Comment: Use `id` (not `name`). And posted form doesn't include `nachname`.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch my fault. ID dosen't work

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` - why?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: @Elliott Frisch. Also NULL

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` you can not retrieve parameters using plain `request.getParameter`.

Remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` it will work

Comment: in addition to the above answer check this link to know more about enctype https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean